# Discrete Schrödinger equation and Fourier transformation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, fourier-transform, discrete

I am currently working on an exercise involving the discretized version of Schrödinger's equation in an infinite potential well. The problem involves a well with a width of 1 and assumes $$\frac{\hbar}{2m} = 1$$ for simplification.

The exercise requires solving the following differential equation:
$$\frac{d\tilde{\psi}_f(t)}{dt} = \frac{2i}{\Delta x^2} \left( \cos\left(\frac{L}{2\pi\Delta x}f\right) - 1 \right) \tilde{\psi}_f(t)$$
where $\tilde{\psi}_f(t)$
is the Fourier transform of the wave equation. I am encountering difficulties in solving this equation.

Additionally, the exercise instructs to transform the spatially discretized wave function $\psi_j(t=0)$ into momentum space, calculate the momentum components at different times (e.g., $t∈\{0.002,0.005,0.010\}$), and then transform them back into position space. I have a program capable of performing Fourier transforms and their inverses on an array, but I am uncertain about the specific steps or calculations involved in this transformation.

Any guidance or assistance in understanding and solving these aspects of the exercise would be greatly appreciated.